# Adding Warning icon to Bootstrap Dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I am using **BootstrapDialog** to show a warning, Where i am not able to show warning icon in the same.

Is there any way/method/key to set icon in **BootstrapDailog** code.

```
new BootstrapDialog()
     .setTitle('Warning')
     .setMessage('Warning on your action.')
     .setType(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING)
     .open();
```

In my case this dialog is common to all the pages. so, preferred to achieve this using script instead of HTML modal.

using: bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap-dialog.min.css and bootstrap-dialog.min.js.

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Message-Box-Notification-Plugin-lobibox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title could be

```
String or Object(html)
```

You can try to set title as "ICON + title text"

```
.setTitle($('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert">').append('Warning'))
```

Comment: @srinuvasanv Mark it as resolved if that answer solved your problem